# How to make websocket response show in same widget as sent message like proper chat screen

Tags: dart, flutter

I am new to flutter and so far I'm currently in love with it.

I need a way to put the response from web-socket server on the left side; like a proper chat screen.

```
  WebSocketChannel channel;
  final List<String> list = [];
  final List<ChatMessageListItem> _messages = <ChatMessageListItem>[];
  TextEditingController _textController;
  bool _isComposing = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    channel = IOWebSocketChannel.connect('ws://echo.websocket.org');
    _textController = TextEditingController();
    channel.stream.listen((receivedMessage){
      setState(() {
        list.add(receivedMessage);
      });
    });
  }
```

The code that displays the sent message

```
void _handleSubmitted(String text) {
    setState(() {
      _isComposing = false;
    });
    if (_textController.text.isNotEmpty) {
      _textController.clear();

      ChatMessageListItem message = new ChatMessageListItem(
        sentMessage: text,
        animationController: new AnimationController(
          duration: new Duration(milliseconds: 350),
          vsync: this,
        ),
      );
      setState(() {
        _messages.insert(0, message);
      });
      message.animationController.forward();
      channel.sink.add(message.sentMessage);
    }
  }
```

//The Widget for showing sent Messages

```
new Flexible(
     child: new ListView.builder(
              padding: new EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              reverse: true,
              itemBuilder: (_, int index) => _messages[index],
              itemCount: _messages.length,
            ),
          )
```

presently I am only able to show the received messages by using the below map

```
new Flexible(
            child: Column(
              children: list.map((receivedMessage) => Text(receivedMessage)).toList(),
            ),
          ),
```

Please, I need a way to make it display inside the ListView Builder.

[The present result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lu3XP.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of keeping two separate lists for sent and received messages, why not just have one list of ChatMessageListItem for both? You can differentiate them using a property called type: sent or received, so you can determine to display on the left or right side of the ListView, different colors, etc. When a receivedMessage comes in, add it to the list. Now your ListView can handle both types of messages.

```
  WebSocketChannel channel;
  //final List<String> list = []; //Remove this line
  final List<ChatMessageListItem> _messages = <ChatMessageListItem>[];
  TextEditingController _textController;
  bool _isComposing = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    channel = IOWebSocketChannel.connect('ws://echo.websocket.org');
    _textController = TextEditingController();
    channel.stream.listen((receivedMessage){
      setState(() {
        _messages.insert(0, new ChatMessageListItem(message: receivedMessage, type: MessageType.received));
        //list.add(receivedMessage);
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thank you; just what I needed.